# Finding MP3 length in C#

Tags: c#, mp3

I'm using [TagLib#](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp) to get ID3 tag data from some MP3s, but what I can't seem to do is find the length of the MP3.  How can I find the length of an MP3 in C#?

Comment: Kind of duplicated question; I tried to answer that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383164/how-to-retrieve-duration-of-mp3-in-net/13269914#13269914

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[TagLib#](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp) exposes this information TagLib.File.Properties.Duration

Comment: That was easy to get it to work, but it's returning about 70% of the real duration of all the files I tried it with.

Comment: I can't say I've tested it tbh so you could be right.  I get the impression calculating duration from headers is an inexact science.

Comment: I've tested taglib-sharp and it was max. 1 seconds wrong. this library does not use the file length to get the duration, so i'll definitely go with this.

Comment: I use NAudio instead to get proper duration for media files; the obtained information seem to be correct since it allowed me to implement a functionality that can "guess" a discid from a set of mp3 files which I can use to query album information from freedb...