# calculating time duration of a file

Tags: c#, file, audio

Dupe of [calculate playing time of a .mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090507/calculate-playing-time-of-a-mp3-file)

im reading a audio file(for ex:wav,mp3 etc) and get a 
long value as duration.now i want to convert that long value 
into correct time duration(like,00:05:32)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on exactly what the `long` represents, you could probably use one of the [`TimeSpan` constructor overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.timespan.aspx) to get a `TimeSpan` object representing the duration of the sound file.

Assuming the `long` represents milliseconds:

```
long soundLength = GetSoundLength();
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, soundLength);
Console.WriteLine("{0} minutes and {1} seconds", duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds);
```

Edit: fixed the contstructor call; it was one parameter short.

Answer (score 1):

First you should determine what it is that you are receiving as input.
Then you can convert this into a TimeSpan object which is easy to work with and display onscreen. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[taglib-sharp](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/TagLib_Sharp) gives you the mp3 duration exactly as you like.

and it's this easy to call

```
TagLib.File mp3file = TagLib.File.Create("exactFilePath");
Console.WriteLine(mp3file.Properties.Duration);
```