# How to retrieve the correct Duration of an mp3 audio file in C#/.NET/DirectX?

Tags: c#, .net, directx, mp3

I am writing a media presentation program, and I am nearly complete, but for some reason I am getting incorrect durations of mp3 files. I use the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Audio class to play audio files, and it works well for wav files. From google search, I can tell that it seems to be a problem when the mp3s are encoded using a variable bit rate, however I need my program to report accurately regardless of the bit rate settings of the media. Here is the code:

```
Media_Audio aud = (Media_Audio)item.MediaFile;
TimeSpan total = aud.EndTime - aud.StartTime;
if (aud.EndTime.TotalSeconds == 0)
{
    total = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(aud.Player.Duration)-aud.StartTime;
}
TimeSpan now = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(aud.Player.CurrentPosition) - aud.StartTime;
string nows = now.Hours.ToString() + ":" + now.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + now.Seconds.ToString();
string tots = total.Hours.ToString() + ":" + total.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + total.Seconds.ToString();
item.currentPosition.Text = nows + "/" + tots;
```

The key line being:

```
total = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(aud.Player.Duration)-aud.StartTime;
```

aud.Player is an instance of Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Audio.

For a song that is, in fact, 5:49 seconds long, it reports 39:13 as the duration. The same length as Windows Explorer and VLC Player. Also, have the K-Lite Mega Codec pack installed. so it could be interfering. I am aware of this question: [How to retrieve duration of MP3 in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383164/how-to-retrieve-duration-of-mp3-in-net)
However, at this stage in my program I do not have the time to switch from my current method of playing audio files to a new one, so do I have any other options to determine the duration using DirectX only? Or Will I have to resort to BASS.NET or TagLib Sharp? (And does meta-data even contain accurate information for VBR-encoded mp3s?)

Comment: There is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214040/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-mp3-in-c-sharp

Comment: Kind of duplicated question; I tried to answer that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383164/how-to-retrieve-duration-of-mp3-in-net/13269914#13269914

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to post it as a comment to @anantoline, but it was too long...  He is right!

Length of the VBR file CAN'T be estimated at all.  Every mp3 frame inside of it could have different bitrate, so from reading any part of the file you can't know what density of the data is at any other part of the file.  Only way of determining EXACT length of VBR mp3 is to DECODE it in whole, OR (if you know how) read all the headers of the frames one by one, and collect their decoded DURATION.

You will use later method only if the CPU that you use is a precious resource that you need to save.  Otherwise, decode the whole file and you'll have the duration.

You can use my port of mpg123 to do the job: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123net/

More: many mp3 files have "stuff" added to it, as a id3 tags, and if you don't go through all the file you could mistakenly use that tag in duration calculation.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, and @anantholine. CPU is precious as it is possible that the user could be playing several HD videos at the same time as they are trying to load this audio file, so I will experiment with your mpg123 project and see if I can get it to work in my context, thanks for yall's help!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible to determine the correct length of a VBR encoded MP3 file without running through the entire file once (some sort of decoding/playback even if not presented has to happen).

You can try to read the ID3 tag to get the length (written there by an app that originally encoded the track/decoded the track once. However, it is possible that the MP3 file provided has no ID3 tags or worse - the wrong value in the ID3 tag.

Comment: what is your source for this? the length can at least be very accurately estimated

Comment: @Артём Царионов Without reading/decoding the entire file even once? I'd like to see a link to an article or source, please.

Comment: the article itself says: "php5 class (will not work in php4)
for detecting bitrate and duration of regular mp3 files (not VBR files)"