# Get MP3 File Lengths

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, mp3

I have 20 mp3 chapter files in a list (per audio book) in  a WPF c# that i need to parse to get the lengths of.

I'm currently looping around the following code which is hugely inefficient

```
MediaElement currentmp3 = new MediaElement();

currentmp3.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
currentmp3.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

currentmp3.MediaOpened += new RoutedEventHandler(currentMp3_MediaOpened);
currentmp3.Source = new Uri(filename);
currentmp3.Play();
currentmp3.Pause();

currentmp3.UpdateLayout();
// if i dont add this it doesnt give the time.
Thread.Sleep(1000);

if (currentmp3.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
    chapter.ChapterLength = currentmp3.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;

currentmp3.Stop();
```

It takes up to 30 seconds to process.

Any suggestions on how to improve performance or anyone aware of any native / 3rd party utils that can do the same job quicker ?

Comment: This information is probably saved in the file format itself. Maybe look for a library that can read the ID3 tags.

Comment: Please try to keep tags like "C#" out of your titles. Instead, just keep them in the tags.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214040/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-mp3-in-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding MP3 length in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007547/finding-mp3-length-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to read the `ID3 tags` in the `MP3` files. This should allow you to get the data you need faster.

This `library` contains everything that you should need, but the question is if it's in the `ID3 tag` or if you need to scan the file (which takes time).
http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/

This library might also be useful.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123net/