# taglib# returns wrong duration

Tags: mp3, taglib, taglib-sharp

I'm getting the duration of an MP3 file in this way:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(fileName);
var duration = file.Properties.Duration;
```

and it is consistently giving me a duration between 68 and 75% of the real duration. Windows File Manager, VLC and just playing the MP3 and measuring with a stopwatch agree on the other duration.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Problem might be in the fact that your file is VBR, ...  a proper way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383164/how-to-retrieve-duration-of-mp3-in-net/13269914#13269914

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605765