# MediaElement.NaturalDuration is less than the actual duration of the audio

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

On some audio files the value of MediaElement.NaturalDuration is less than the actual duration of the audio. When I open the file in Windows Media Player the duration is correct (also when I look at the properties of the file). Although the value of the NaturalDuration property is incorrect, the audio is played fully, but at some point the value of the Position property becomes greater than the value of the NaturalDuration property, which, as I understand, should never happen.

I have created a simple application to reproduce the problem: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=ACF8BFD4384116CE!2908&authkey=!AG-wF6Ae-7EAYk8

The duration of the audio file used in the application is 00:02:54, but the value of the NaturalDuration property is 00:01:59.

Does anyone know why and if there is a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you checking the value of `NaturalDuration` after the `MediaOpened` event has been called?

Comment: Yes. Also I was trying to see if it changes while the audio is played, but it doesn't. As I mentioned the value of the Position property is becoming greater than the duration after it passes the 00:01:59 mark.

Comment: WMP displays correct time 2:54. But iTunes displays 1:59. Actually if we take file size and suppose this file has constant 16 kbps it gives us ~3 min. But if we use frames and do some wrong assumption regarding frames or number of samples per frame we can get something else. Sometimes duration can be taken even from some special headers. Who knows what do they do.. If somebody knows - please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is not an answer but some results of a short investigation that give some clues why it behaves like that and where those numbers come from (2:58 and 1:59). First look at this thread: [Calculating the length of MP3 Frames in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220660/calculating-the-length-of-mp3-frames-in-milliseconds)
Two things that we will use from there:

1) Frame length (in ms) = (samples per frame / sample rate (in hz)) * 1000, and

Duration in sec = Frame length (in ms) * number of frames / 1000

2) There are some standards regarding number of samples for different MPEG versions:
Samples per frame:

MPEG Version 1

```
        384,    // Layer1
        1152,   // Layer2
        1152    // Layer3
```

MPEG Version 2 & 2.5

```
        384,    // Layer1
        1152,   // Layer2
        576     // Layer3
```

Now lets check in winamp what it says about files format info:

MPEG-2.5 layer 3

16 kbps, 2482 frames

Now if you take frames = 2482 and samples per frame = 576 (MPEG-2.5 layer 3) you'll get duration 2:58. But it looks like for some reason silverlight and iTunes uses samples per frame = 384 which gives us 1:59. Next step could be to check the real values of file's headers and if they are correct and it is possible to calculate correct duration - well than you could cook up some hack to get durations separately (from the server for example). But I'm pretty sure - that file has some defects (inconsistent headers and content) and some players can handle it, others - not.

Comment: That is very useful. Thank you! I will try to investigate what is wrong with that file. Maybe indeed the only solution will be to get the duration separately on the server.