# How do i get the framelength of audio in android?

Tags: java, android, audio

> How do I get the framelength, and other stuff such as the framesize, channels, etc., of an audio file in android?

I tried using the MediaFormat but I thinks its for formatting an audio not getting the details from it. Also, is there a way to import a javax.sound library to android so that if there's no way in getting the framelength, I will just use the classes in **javax.sound**?

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(yourActivity, Uri.parse(pathofyourrecording));
int duration = mp.getDuration();
```

Comment: and the duration will give me...?

Comment: time duration in seconds.

Comment: I'mm sorry that doesn't seem to answer my question. What will I do to the duration to get the framelength, framesize, etc.?

Comment: Just give a look at below link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220660/calculating-the-length-of-mp3-frames-in-milliseconds

Comment: There is nothing there that helped me. I just had the audio file and by that I need to get its details (framelength, framesize, chanels, samplerate, framerate, sample size in bits) the things that you see when you use AudioInputStream class in javax.sound.