# How can I calculate the audio time by byte position (bytes to secounds)?

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, ffmpeg-php

I have the audio file and byte range. I want get time for each byte position. I'm use php.

I tried to calculate that using this formula: `$time = $byte/($bitRate * $sampleRate * $cannels)`
But it doesn't work.

So how can I calculate this? I used ffmpeg (php-ffmpeg), and if you know how to find this data with ffmpeg, that would be fine;

Comment: What format is the audio file?

Comment: @llogan  audio format is mp3

Comment: See [Calculating the length of MP3 Frames in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6220660/) and `ffprobe` can be helpful: `ffprobe -show_packets input.mp3`