# Get duration of IFormFile MP3 in ASP.NET Core 2.2 WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, mp3, webapi, iformfile

I have a WebAPI consuming an MP3 file as an IFormFile. I am able to save the file with no issue but I want to get the duration of the file in minutes and seconds before Saving it to Disk. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: "before Saving it to Disk"： why not read duration from the stream like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269914/10091607)?

Comment: @itminus will give it a try and report back